# Trying to install WCF with IIS7 and Net Framework 4.0

Tags: wcf, iis-7, localhost, .net-framework-version

When I run my WCF service in my `localhost` I get the following error:

`HTTP 404.3 - Not Found` with and error code 0x80070032.

Right now I'm trying to install WCF by running `ServiceModelReg.exe -ia` in folder:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319

In command prompt I get an error saying `ServiceModelReg.exe does not support WOW mode`

What does it mean and how can I install WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to folder:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319

and try again.

[List of commands for ServiceModelReg.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012(v=vs.110).aspx)